# Django database image stopped showing

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-database, django-imagekit

The image from the django database was showing fine on the home page and the detail page of my project. But later when I clicked on the product image from the home page, the image disappeared on the detail page. The only data that get displayed are product name and product price but not product image.

What could be the cause?

[[detail image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M95fc.png)] [[image on home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE3fN.png)][database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtQIF.png) [detail page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsToi.png)[view for home pagr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIFLc.png)

I change the database from sqlite3 to postgreSql because I thought it could be the cause but it didn't work.
I installed Pillow but it is still the same, it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a moment to [tour] the site. To ask a question, see [ask], and why you probably should add a [example].

Comment: Post as text not images. See [Do not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)